# Can't redirect HTTP to HTTPS on NGINX

Tags: nginx

i have been trying for a couple of days to configure my SSL certificate on NGINX, i got it working but tried different ways to redirect my HTTP traffic to HTTPS, all configurations i tried failed, i copied my config file below (or what is left of it) for someone to take a look at it, SSL is working when i tipe https://example.com, but i can't make it work when typing www.example.com, keep getting error 404 cannot redirect traffic to https, i commented the ssl lines so i can keep my website running on port 80 until i figure this out, any help will be apreciated, thanks

```
#include /etc/nginx/blockuseragents.rules;
#        server {
#        if ($blockedagent) {
#               return 403;
#        }
#        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
#        return 444;
#        }
#        listen [::]:80;
#        listen 80;
#        server_name example.com www.example.com;
#
#
#       listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
#       listen 443 ssl http2;
#        server_name www.example.com;
#
#         ssl off;
# SSL configuration
#        #
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
#        ssl_ciphers  'ECDH !aNULL !eNULL !SSLv2 !SSLv3';
#        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/file.crt;
#        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
#        server_name www.example.com;
#
#        root "/var/www/example.com/html/web";
#        index index.html index.htm index.php;
#        charset utf-8;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?r=$1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need separate server {} sections in your configuration for each site you want to serve, and given that you want different behaviour based on whether the user arrives at `http:` or `https:` these must be defined as separate server {} sections.

In one, you would listen on port 80, and the other, you'd listen on port 443 and enable ssl and http2.

In the one that listens on port 80, the only thing you want to declare in that section is a redirect to the same URL but with `https:`.

On my site these redirect stubs look like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name some.example.com;

        return 301 https://some.example.com$request_uri;
}
```